# Why can I not use certain resolutions with certain refresh rates?

Tags: resolution

I'm a competitive CS player that enjoys playing 4:3 resolutions. The problem comes when I try to play 1280x960 black bars (maintain aspect ratio), It will not allow this resolution on 144hz or 120hz options. Anything lower than that and it works fine.

Here's a list of resolutions that do NOT work with 144hz and Maintain aspect ratio option:
1280x768(16:10), 1280x960, 1280x1024, 1360x1024, 1400x1050, 1600x900(16;9) and 1680x1050 (16:10)

Some resolutions that work fine with all hz:
1920x1080, 1366x768, 1024x768, 800x600

Can you guess what problem is?

Comment: Yes: it's at least one of CS, the video card or the monitor. You could use a setting which gives you your preferred refresh rate and resolution and put black card over the monitor to show a 4:3 aspect ratio.

Comment: Actually, its not related to CS. I cant set 144hz on 1280x960 on desktop. It turns 640x480 automatically when I try to set 144hz on 1280x960. Any guess?

Comment: Look at the specifications for your monitor to see what it supports.

Comment: I'm using Benq XL2411Z. Of course, this monitor supports all of resolutions like 1920x1080@144Hz.

Comment: At a *guess*, choosing 19" (4:3) in the Display Mode settings on the monitor, as described on page 42 of the [monitor's manual](http://zowie.benq.com/content/dam/game/en/support/download/monitor/xl/xl2411/user-manual/user-manual-monitor-xl2411-en.pdf) might do it.

Comment: Display mode is greyed out. How can I fix it? May it be related to my problem?

Answer (score -1):

Forget all things about monitor settings, drivers, control panels, etc. Just install windows 8.1 and enjoy your life. Its fixed!